# sql results to show in datagrid vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm working on a school project and I'm stuck, real bad. I've gone through many websites and tried all the suggestions that I came across and still have nothing. I have tried filtering the datagrid and SQL statements with no luck and the professor is stumped. Some responses to other posts say to use Dataview.Filter but the does not come up as an option for me in VS 2013 and I am using Office 2010.

Here is the problem. I have a form with CustomerID, FirstName, LastName as data bound text boxes to an access db table. The datagrid is bound to the same db with the columns CustomerID, DateEntered, Notes.

I would like the the information in the datagrid to show all the notes that are associated with the CustomerID that is on the form. For instance: If the CustomerID on the form is 2, then all the notes in the datagrid associated with the ID should show. Right now I'm trying to do this with an SQL statement and have tried it in different areas and no luck. Here is the code that I am trying to use with a click event and I have no idea if this is correct. The datagrid still shows all the notes for all the customers so I am guessing that something is missing to say where the results should be placed. Please help.

```
Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click


        Dim SQLstr As String

SQLstr = "SELECT Notes.CustomerID, Notes.MemoEntered, Notes.Notes, Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName"

SQLstr = "FROM (Notes INNER JOIN Customer ON Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID AND Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID)"

SQLstr = "WHERE Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID"

End Sub
```

Comment: Your changing your string each time...

Comment: That code is quite useless for a number of reasons.  Before we can help you, we would would need to know whether you want to retrieve all the data from the database up front and then filter the local copy as required or you want to retrieve only what data you need when you need it.  Each of those is done quite differently.  If you're talking about using the `RowFilter` property of a `DataView` (NOT `Filter`, which doesn't exist) then that would suggest the former but using SQL code on each click would suggest the latter.  How can you possibly write code when you don't know what it has to do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do about an hour or two after posting it. Here is what I did to get the results that I wanted:

Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

```
    Dim SQLstr As String

    SQLstr = "SELECT Notes.CustomerID, Notes.MemoEntered, Notes.Notes, Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName"
    SQLstr = "FROM (Notes INNER JOIN Customer ON Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID AND Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID)"
    SQLstr = "WHERE Notes.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID"

    NotesBindingSource.Filter = "[CustomerID] = '" & CustomerIDTextBox.Text & "'"
    DataGridView1.Refresh()


End Sub
```

Adding the two lines at the bottom did the trick and now I can see only the notes that are associated with the customer that I am viewing. Thank you.

Raj